# Classic ASP sessions getting lost in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, session, asp-classic

I am developing a legacy application in Classic ASP. I am experiencing a strange problem with Internet Explorer. I set certain session variables in a page and retrieve them on another page.

This is working perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.

But in Internet Explorer, most of the times, it is dropping the values in the session variables. This is in IE 7, 8 and 9.

If I move to a different page after a long time, the session data is retained. But if I move to the page within a short time, the session data is not retained. The retrieved session variable is empty.

Any help would help me get past this stumbling block!

Edit:

The code is plain and simple, just setting some session variables and when i move away from that page, they are lost and this happens only in INTERNET EXPLORER.

Comment: Could you provide some relevant code that involves your problem? It is difficult to see the problem based on your current question, because it should work fine.

Comment: This sounds like it could have something to do with cookie retention and/or caching settings on windows.  Is this for IE on  *all* workstations or just IE with a server on localhost?  IE prevents certain resources from loading/executing when accessing a server on localhost, i seem to remember.

Comment: Its very difficult to imagine how what you have described can really be happening in light of this bit "If I move to a different page after a long time, the session data is retained. But if I move to the page within a short time, the session data is not retained. "  You should create a pair of very, very simple pages that demonstrates the problem and include their code in your question.  At the very least you can then have others say "It works for me" then you'll know you have some very strange config issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that i could have to do with `response.buffer = true`
if redirecting to other page try add `response.clear` before the redirect and `response.end` at the end of the page just before `</body></html>`

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem with IE10

Make sure you don't have the delete history checkbox checked.

Tools > Internet Options >  Browsing History

For some reason this affected both Session variables and Cookies.